# Alias for ssh client to autofill subnet

Tags: bash, ssh

I'd like to be able to run `ssh 142` (for example) from a bash prompt and have it automatically expand to `ssh 10.33.7.142`.  I'm thinking I should be able to do this from .bashrc, but I can't figure out how to detect if a command-line argument is a single octet, and if so, automatically add a subnet before it.

I'd like to implement this on my CentOS LXC host nodes.  The vast majority of the time when ssh is used on them it is to connect to a container running on them, all of which are in the same subnet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function in your .bashrc like this:

```
ssh=$(which ssh) # the real ssh binary
ssh(){
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then # if first arg to ssh is an integer
    $ssh 10.33.7.$1               # then ssh with prepended subnet
  else
    $ssh $@                       # else just do some regular ssh
  fi
}
```

Comment: Giles, is there any reason to prefer `$()` over backticks other than nesting?

Comment: That almost works, but it sometimes runs both ssh commands.  Maybe based upon the exit status of the first one?

Comment: "Maybe based upon the exit status " yep. fixed :)

Comment: What is the || for?

Comment: A priest, a minister, and a rabbit walk into a bar, and the rabbit says,
"I might be a typo". (fixed)

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` :

```
Host 142
Hostname 10.33.7.142
```

Now you can run :

```
ssh 142
```

To generate the config file :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read host; do
    echo -e "Host $host\nHostname 10.33.7.$host\n"
done < <(printf '%s\n' {1..254})
```

Comment: 142 was an example.  Looking for a solution that can work for any value without having to enumerate them all in a config file.

Comment: Check edited answer with code to generate config file for a full range of host ids